# How high are you when you are three miles away from the threshold of the landing RWY and get 3 white and 1 red on PAPI?

Tags: visual-approaches

Let's say you were shooting a visual approach and you were precisely on a three mile final. You gave a glance at the PAPI, you find it giving three white and one red. How high you are from the 3 degree glide path at the moment?

Anybody can do math for me?

Comment: Depends on the angle to which the PAPI is aligned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to AIM 2-1-4, three white one red would equal 3.2 degrees above the horizontal. Doing some math, and assuming you are 3 NM from the TDZ (ie the PAPI) and ignoring slant range error, 3 NM would put you 18,228 ft from the threshold. Assuming you were on the 3 degree PAPI glideslope, you would then be 955.3 ft above TDZE. If .2 degrees high, or 3 white one red, you would be at 1019.1 ft above TDZE, or about 64 ft above the correct glideslope.

Math if you care: [tan(3.2)*18,228]-[tan(3)*18,228].

Comment: Bravo! Thanks :)

Comment: That depends on the angle of the PAPI though. Not all runways have the same approach angle.

Comment: @J.Hougaard while this is the case, I was working off the information available in AIM 2-1-4, which states the PAPI glidepath is 3.00 degrees.